# TEST APEX - How to cover size() > 0 in WrapperClass

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class

I'm trying to cover a condition that verify if my list isn't empty.

But no matter what i'm trying it cover the SOQL query but doesn't cover the if statement as you can see below.

[image]

The way i'm trying to cover this is like this :

```
@IsTest
        static void validateOffreSeminaire_WithExistingFacturesAcompte_ShouldReturnInvalidWrapper() {
                        
            sofactoapp__Product_configuration__c pc = new sofactoapp__Product_configuration__c(
                Name = 'Séminaire',
                Is_B2B__c = true,
                Statut__c = 'Validée',                                                                                                      
                Emetteur__c = [SELECT ID FROM sofactoapp__Raison_Sociale__c WHERE sofactoapp__is_default__c = true Limit 1].Id
            );
            insert pc;
            System.debug('##### pc' + pc);
            
            // Création de compte B2B
            Account account = new Account(
                Name= 'Compte Test B2B '
            );
            insert account;

                        
        // Création de contacts liés aux comptes B2B
            Contact contact = new Contact(
                AccountId = account.Id,
                LastName = 'Contact Test '
            );
            insert contact;
            
            Product2 product = new Product2(
                Name = 'LOCA - Auditorium équipé - Demi journée',
                Type_de_produit__c = 'Séminaires / Event',
                Inclure_CA__c = true,
                IsActive = true,
                TVA__c = 20
            );
            insert product;
            System.debug('##### product' + product);
            
            sofactoapp__Product_rule__c pr = new sofactoapp__Product_rule__c(
                sofactoapp__Produit__c = product.Id,
                sofactoapp__Taux_de_TVA_list__c = '20%',
                sofactoapp__Product_configuration__c = pc.Id
            );
            insert pr;
            System.debug('##### pr' + pr);
            
            PricebookEntry pricebookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
                Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
                Product2Id = product.Id,
                UnitPrice = 0,
                IsActive = true
            );
            insert pricebookEntry;
            
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Opp Seminaire',
                AccountId = account.Id,
                RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsActive = true AND DeveloperName = 'EVENT' AND SobjectType = 'Opportunity'].Id,
                Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
                CloseDate = Date.today(),
                StageName = '4. Gagnée'
            );
            insert opp;
            
             System.debug('##### oppSeminaire ' + opp);
            
            OpportunityLineItem opli = new OpportunityLineItem(
                OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                Product2Id = product.Id,
                Quantity = 1,
                UnitPrice = 2500,
                PricebookEntryId = pricebookEntry.Id
            );
            insert opli;
            
            sofactoapp__Offre__c offre = new sofactoapp__Offre__c(
                Name = 'Offre Seminaire',
                sofactoapp__Compte__c = account.Id,
                sofactoapp__Raison_sociale__c = [SELECT ID FROM sofactoapp__Raison_Sociale__c WHERE sofactoapp__is_default__c = true Limit 1].Id,
                sofactoapp__Product_configuration__c = pc.Id,
                sofactoapp__Payment_mode__c = 'Virement',
                sofactoapp__Opportunite__c = opp.Id,
                sofactoapp__Contact__c = contact.Id
            );
            insert offre;
            System.debug('##### offreSeminaire ' + offre);
            
            sofactoapp__Poste_offre__c posteOffre = new sofactoapp__Poste_offre__c(
                sofactoapp__Offre__c = offre.Id,
                sofactoapp__Designation__c = 'LOCA - Auditorium équipé - Demi journée',
                sofactoapp__Produit__c = product.Id,
                sofactoapp__Quantite__c = 1,
                sofactoapp__Prix_Unitaire_HT__c = 2500,
                sofactoapp__Taux_de_remise__c = 0,
                sofactoapp__Taux_de_TVA_list__c = '20%'
            );
            insert posteOffre;
            
            //List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c> listFactureAcompte = new List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c>();
            
            sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c factureAcompte = new sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c(
                Libelle__c = 'Facture acompte',
                sofactoapp__Compte__c = offre.sofactoapp__Compte__c, 
                sofactoapp__Contact__c = offre.sofactoapp__Contact__c,
                sofactoapp__Donnee_Comptable__c = offre.sofactoapp__Donnee_Comptable__c,
                sofactoapp__emetteur_facture__c = offre.sofactoapp__Raison_sociale__c,
                Facture_acompte__c = true,
                sofactoapp__Date_de_facture__c = date.today(),
                sofactoapp__Etape__c = 'A valider',
                sofactoapp__Etat__c = 'Brouillon',
                sofactoapp__Offre__c = offre.Id,
                sofactoapp__Opportunit__c = opp.Id,
                sofactoapp__Payment_mode__c = 'Virement',
                sofactoapp__Sous_type__c = 'Facture'
            );
            //listFactureAcompte.add(factureAcompte);
            insert factureAcompte;
            //insert listFactureAcompte;
            //System.debug('##### listFactureAcompte ' + listFactureAcompte);
            
            System.debug('##### factureAcompte ' + factureAcompte);
            
            sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c ligne = new sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c(
                sofactoapp__Facture__c = factureAcompte.Id,
                sofactoapp__Description__c = 'LOCA - Auditorium équipé - Demi journée',
                sofactoapp__Produit__c = product.Id,
                sofactoapp__Quantit__c = 1,
                sofactoapp__Prix_Unitaire_HT__c = 2500,
                sofactoapp__Taux_Remise__c = 0,
                sofactoapp__Taux_de_TVA_list__c = '20%'
            );
            insert ligne;
            
            List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c> checkIfFactureAcompte = [SELECT Id, sofactoapp__Amount_exVAT__c, sofactoapp__Amount_VAT__c, sofactoapp__TVA_pc__c, Facture_acompte__c FROM sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id =: offre.Id AND Facture_acompte__c = true];
            System.debug('##### checkFactureAcompteSize ' + checkIfFactureAcompte.size());
            System.debug('##### checkIfFactureAcompte ' + checkIfFactureAcompte);
            
            
            SOF_Facture_Helper helper = new SOF_Facture_Helper();
            SOF_Facture_Helper.OffreSeminaireValidationWrapper validation = helper.validateOffreSeminaire(offre.Id, 0.3);

            System.assertEquals(1, checkIfFactureAcompte.size());
            //System.assertEquals(null, checkIfFactureAcompte.size());
            System.assertEquals(true, factureAcompte.Facture_acompte__c);
            //System.assertEquals(true, validation.errorMessage.contains('Une facture d\'acompte existe déjà.'));
        }
```

But with this, this isn't even covering the SOQL and the if statement.

It is with those methods i'm having some coverage :

```
@IsTest
        static void validateOffreSeminaire_WithoutMissingFields_ShouldReturnValidWrapper() {
            sofactoapp__Offre__c offre = createOffre(1, '12', false, false, SOF_DataFactory.PERIODICITE_ANNUELLE);
            offre.sofactoapp__Contact__c = retrieveIds().contact;
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                    Id = offre.sofactoapp__Opportunite__c,
                    StageName = '4. Gagnée'
            );
            update opp;
            update offre;
            
            SOF_Facture_Helper helper = new SOF_Facture_Helper();
            SOF_Facture_Helper.OffreSeminaireValidationWrapper validation = helper.validateOffreSeminaire(offre.Id, 0.3);
            System.assertEquals(true, validation.isValid);
        }

        @IsTest
        static void validateOffreSeminaire_WithInvalidOpportunityStage() {
            sofactoapp__Offre__c offre = createOffre(1, '12', false, false, SOF_DataFactory.PERIODICITE_ANNUELLE);
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                    Id = offre.sofactoapp__Opportunite__c,
                    StageName = '3. Accord'
            );
            update opp;
            SOF_Facture_Helper helper = new SOF_Facture_Helper();
            SOF_Facture_Helper.OffreSeminaireValidationWrapper validation = helper.validateOffreSeminaire(offre.Id, 0.3);

            System.assertEquals(false, validation.isValid);
            System.assertEquals(true, validation.errorMessage.contains('L\'opportunité associée à cette offre n\'est pas indiquée comme \'4. Gagnée\'. La génération des factures n\'est pas encore possible.'));
        }
        
        @IsTest
        static void validateOffreSeminaire_WithMissingeQuotationFields() {
            
            SOF_DataFactory.OrgIdsWrapper ids = retrieveIds();
            
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
                Name = 'Opp Seminaire',
                AccountId = ids.compte,
                RecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsActive = true AND DeveloperName = 'EVENT' AND SobjectType = 'Opportunity'].Id,
                Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
                CloseDate = Date.today(),
                StageName = '4. Gagnée'
            );
            insert opp;
            
             System.debug('##### oppSeminaire ' + opp);
            
            sofactoapp__Offre__c offre = new sofactoapp__Offre__c(
                Name = 'Offre Seminaire',
                sofactoapp__Compte__c = ids.compte,
                sofactoapp__Raison_sociale__c = ids.raisonSociale,
                sofactoapp__Product_configuration__c = null,
                sofactoapp__Payment_mode__c = 'Virement',
                sofactoapp__Opportunite__c = opp.Id
            );
            insert offre;
            System.debug('##### offreSeminaire ' + offre);
            SOF_Facture_Helper helper = new SOF_Facture_Helper();
            SOF_Facture_Helper.OffreSeminaireValidationWrapper validation = helper.validateOffreSeminaire(offre.Id, 0.3);

            System.assertEquals(false, validation.isValid);
            System.assertEquals(true, validation.errorMessage.contains('Un contact, mode de paiement ainsi qu\'une configuration produit doit être renseignés pour émettre une facture.'));
        }
```

I add the WrapperClass i'm trying to cover to be more clear :

```
public OffreSeminaireValidationWrapper validateOffreSeminaire(Id offreId, Decimal tauxAcompte) {
        
        Id idFactureAcompte;
        Decimal getTauxFactureAcompte;
        Decimal tauxFactureAcompte;
        Decimal tauxModifie;
        Decimal montantHTAvecProduitsSupp;
        Decimal montantTTCAvecProduitsSupp;
        
        sofactoapp__Offre__c offre = retrieveOffre(offreId);
        System.debug('##### offreFromHelperId ' + offre.Id);

        OffreSeminaireValidationWrapper validationWrapper = new OffreSeminaireValidationWrapper();
        
        if (offre.sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.StageName != '4. Gagnée') {
            validationWrapper.isValid = false;
            validationWrapper.errorMessage = 'L\'opportunité associée à cette offre n\'est pas indiquée comme \'4. Gagnée\'. La génération des factures n\'est pas encore possible.';
            return validationWrapper;
        }
        
        if (offre.sofactoapp__Contact__c == null || offre.sofactoapp__Payment_mode__c == null || offre.sofactoapp__Product_configuration__c == null) {
            validationWrapper.isValid = false;
            validationWrapper.errorMessage = 'Un contact, mode de paiement ainsi qu\'une configuration produit doit être renseignés pour émettre une facture.';
            return validationWrapper;
        }
        
        /************** Gérer l'affichage en cas de modification du pourcentage sur la facture d'acompte ****************************************/
        
        List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c> checkIfFactureAcompte = [SELECT Id, sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id FROM sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id =: offreId AND Facture_acompte__c = true];
        System.debug('##### checkIfFactureAcompteOffreId ' + checkIfFactureAcompte);
        
        
        if(checkIfFactureAcompte.size() > 0) {
            idFactureAcompte = [SELECT Id FROM sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id =: offreId AND Facture_acompte__c = true].Id;
            getTauxFactureAcompte = [SELECT sofactoapp__Pourcentage__c FROM sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c WHERE sofactoapp__Facture__c =: idFactureAcompte LIMIT 1].sofactoapp__Pourcentage__c;            
            tauxFactureAcompte = getTauxFactureAcompte / 100;
            validationWrapper.showFactAcomptePart = false;
            validationWrapper.errorMessage = 'Une facture d\'acompte existe déjà.';
        }
        else {
            validationWrapper.showFactAcomptePart = true;
        }
        
        /************** Gestion de l'affichage de la partie facture solde ok ou en erreur *********************************************************/
        
        List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c> checkIfFactureSolde = new List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c>([SELECT Id FROM sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id =: offreId AND Facture_solde__c = true]);
                
        if(checkIfFactureSolde.size() > 0 && checkIfFactureAcompte.size() > 0) {
            validationWrapper.allFactureEmitted = true;
            validationWrapper.errorMessage = 'Toutes les factures ont déjà été crées.';
        }
        
        /*************** Recuperer le/les produit(s) ajoutés après la facture d'acompte ********************/
        
        List<sofactoapp__Poste_offre__c> ligneOffres = [SELECT Id, sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c, sofactoapp__Montant_TTC__c FROM sofactoapp__Poste_offre__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__c =:offreId];
        
        Map<Id, sofactoapp__Poste_offre__c> mapLignesOffres = new Map<Id, sofactoapp__Poste_offre__c>(ligneOffres);
        
        List<sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c> ligneFactureAcomptes = [SELECT sofactoapp__Poste_d_offre__c FROM sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c WHERE sofactoapp__Facture__c =: idFactureAcompte];
        
        Map<Id, sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c> mapLigneFactureAcomptes = new Map<Id, sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c>(ligneFactureAcomptes);
        For(sofactoapp__Ligne_de_Facture__c lf: ligneFactureAcomptes)
        {
            mapLigneFactureAcomptes.put(lf.sofactoapp__Poste_d_offre__c, lf);
        }
        
        List<Decimal> lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupps = new List<Decimal>();
        List<Decimal> lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupps = new List<Decimal>();
        
        montantTTCAvecProduitsSupp = 0;
        montantHTAvecProduitsSupp = 0;
        
        for(Id idLignesOffres : mapLignesOffres.keySet() ){
            
            if(checkIfFactureAcompte.size() > 0 && mapLigneFactureAcomptes.containsKey(idLignesOffres)) {
                //Calcul 1 - Tx d'acompte
                tauxModifie = 1 - tauxFactureAcompte;
            }
            else  {
                // calcul coef 1
                tauxModifie = 1;
            }
            
            montantTTCAvecProduitsSupp += mapLignesOffres.get(idLignesOffres).sofactoapp__Montant_TTC__c * tauxModifie;
            montantHTAvecProduitsSupp += mapLignesOffres.get(idLignesOffres).sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c * tauxModifie;
                        
            lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupps.add(montantTTCAvecProduitsSupp);
            lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupps.add(montantHTAvecProduitsSupp);
            
        }
        
        /********************************Gestion des différents cas d'affichage***********************************************/
         
        if(idFactureAcompte != null && tauxFactureAcompte != 0.3 && ligneOffres.size() == ligneFactureAcomptes.size()) {
            validationWrapper.tauxAcompte = tauxFactureAcompte;
            validationWrapper.tauxSolde = 1 - tauxFactureAcompte;
            Decimal tauxSolde = validationWrapper.tauxSolde;
            
            validationWrapper.totalOffreTTC = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_TTC_total__c * validationWrapper.tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreHT = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c * validationWrapper.tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeTTC = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_TTC_total__c * tauxSolde;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeHT = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c * tauxSolde;
            validationWrapper.isValid = validationWrapper.missingFields.isEmpty();            
        }
        else if(idFactureAcompte != null && tauxFactureAcompte == 0.3 && ligneOffres.size() > ligneFactureAcomptes.size()) {
            validationWrapper.tauxAcompte = tauxFactureAcompte;
            validationWrapper.tauxSolde = 1 - tauxFactureAcompte;
            Decimal tauxSolde = validationWrapper.tauxSolde;
            
            validationWrapper.totalOffreTTC = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_TTC_total__c * validationWrapper.tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreHT = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c * validationWrapper.tauxAcompte;
             for(Decimal lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupp : lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupps) {
                validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeTTC = lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupp;
            }
            for(Decimal lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupp : lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupps) {
                 validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeHT = lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupp;
            }
            validationWrapper.isValid = validationWrapper.missingFields.isEmpty(); 
        }
        else if(idFactureAcompte != null && tauxFactureAcompte != 0.3 && ligneOffres.size() > ligneFactureAcomptes.size()) {
            validationWrapper.tauxAcompte = tauxFactureAcompte;
            validationWrapper.tauxSolde = 1 - validationWrapper.tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreTTC = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_TTC_total__c * validationWrapper.tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreHT = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c * validationWrapper.tauxAcompte;
            for(Decimal lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupp : lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupps) {
                validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeTTC = lstMontantsTTCAvecProduitsSupp;
            }
            for(Decimal lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupp : lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupps) {
                 validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeHT = lstMontantsHTAvecProduitsSupp;
            }
            validationWrapper.isValid = validationWrapper.missingFields.isEmpty();
        }
        else {
            validationWrapper.tauxAcompte = tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.tauxSolde = 1 - tauxAcompte;
            Decimal tauxSolde = validationWrapper.tauxSolde;
            
            validationWrapper.totalOffreTTC = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_TTC_total__c * tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreHT = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c * tauxAcompte;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeTTC = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_TTC_total__c * tauxSolde;
            validationWrapper.totalOffreSoldeHT = offre.sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c * tauxSolde;
            validationWrapper.isValid = validationWrapper.missingFields.isEmpty();
        }
        
        return validationWrapper;
    }

@TestVisible
    private sofactoapp__Offre__c retrieveOffre(Id offreId) {
        return [
            SELECT
            Id,
            Paiement_Comptant__c,
            Inclure_Part_Europe__c,
            Generer_Reglements__c,
            sofactoapp__Periodicite__c,
            sofactoapp__Raison_sociale__c,
            sofactoapp__Compte__c,
            sofactoapp__Contact__c,
            sofactoapp__Objet_Offre__c,
            sofactoapp__Commentaires__c,
            sofactoapp__Donnee_Comptable__c,
            sofactoapp__Montant_TTC_total__c,
            sofactoapp__Montant_HT__c,
            sofactoapp__Payment_mode__c,
            sofactoapp__Product_configuration__c,
            sofactoapp__Taux_de_remise__c,
            sofactoapp__Taux_Remise_2__c,
            sofactoapp__Date_de_debut__c,
            sofactoapp__Date_de_fin__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__c,
            sofactoapp__V_R_f__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.Abonnement__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.StageName,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.Opportunite_d_abo_N_1__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.Opportunite_d_abo_N_1__r.Abonnement__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.Opportunite_d_abo_N_1_avant_upgrade__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.Opportunite_d_abo_N_1_avant_upgrade__r.Abonnement__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.sofactoapp__Payment_mode__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.sofactoapp__Date_de_debut__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.sofactoapp__Date_de_fin__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.sofactoapp__Contact__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.ROLLUP_Date_d_echeance_de_l_abonnement__c,
            sofactoapp__Opportunite__r.ROLLUP_Duree_abonnement__c, (
                SELECT sofactoapp__Produit__r.Name,
                sofactoapp__Produit__r.Type_de_produit__c,
                sofactoapp__Produit__r.Type_de_place__c,
                sofactoapp__Designation__c,
                sofactoapp__Quantite__c,
                sofactoapp__Prix_Unitaire_HT__c,
                sofactoapp__PUHT_precis__c,
                sofactoapp__Taux_de_remise__c,
                sofactoapp__Taux_de_TVA_list__c,
                sofactoapp__Taux_de_TVA__c,
                sofactoapp__Total_TTC__c,
                sofactoapp__Total_HT__c,
                sofactoapp__Total_TVA__c,
                sofactoapp__Produit__c,
                sofactoapp__Product_rule__c,
                sofactoapp__Product_rule__r.sofactoapp__Analytique_1__c,
                sofactoapp__Product_rule__r.sofactoapp__Analytique_2__c,
                sofactoapp__Product_rule__r.sofactoapp__Compte_comptable_produit__c,
                sofactoapp__Product_rule__r.sofactoapp__Compte_comptable_TVA__c FROM sofactoapp__Postes_d_offre__r
            ), (
                SELECT Id FROM sofactoapp__Factures__r
            )
            FROM sofactoapp__Offre__c
            WHERE Id =: offreId
            LIMIT 1
        ];
    }
```

I'm really lost and confused about how to cover the part of the if statement, so if anyone can see what i'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you debugged why the first query in picture above on `sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c` is returning 0 records? Maybe the `offreId` variable is not having right value.

Comment: Just tried like this ```List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c> checkIfFactureAcompte = [SELECT Id FROM sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id =: offreId AND Facture_acompte__c = true];
        System.debug('##### checkIfFactureAcompteOffreId ' + checkIfFactureAcompte);``` and in my logs it's like this ```##### checkIfFactureAcompteOffreId ()```

Comment: It doesn't help for my actual case but still is interesting.

Comment: Your "in my logs it's like this `##### checkIfFactureAcompteOffreId ()`" comment shows that it is empty. Have you tried a `System.debug('#### factureAcompte: ' + factureAcompte);` statement **in your test class** immediately after `insert factureAcompte;` to verify that you an `Id` and therefore an actual insertion of your `sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c` object? | Also, what are the results of your `System.debug('##### checkFactureAcompteSize ' + checkIfFactureAcompte.size());` and `System.debug('##### checkIfFactureAcompte ' + checkIfFactureAcompte);` lines **in your test class**?

Comment: I've done it yes and indeed i have an Id of my invoice and it is created. The size gives me 1 and the last system debug returns me ```##### checkIfFactureAcompte (sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c:{Id=a2u7a000000ItYdAAK, sofactoapp__Amount_exVAT__c=2500.00, sofactoapp__Amount_VAT__c=2637.50, sofactoapp__TVA_pc__c=5.50, Facture_acompte__c=true, sofactoapp__Offre__c=a347a000000FTgdAAG})```

Comment: In the class that you are testing, the first line you show us in the image is `List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c> checkIfFactureAcompte = [SELECT Id FROM sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id =: offreId AND Facture_acompte__c = true];`  Where, in the class that you are testing, does it retrieve the `offreId`? Have you verified that the `offreId` has a value? And if so, have you verified that it is the same value as the one you created in your test class?

Comment: I just verified and the offreId is retrieved and is the same. But it seems like ```sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id``` is not correct. When i do ```List<sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c> checkIfFactureAcompte = [SELECT Id, sofactoapp__Amount_exVAT__c, sofactoapp__Amount_VAT__c, sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id FROM sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c WHERE sofactoapp__Offre__r.Id =: offre.Id AND Facture_acompte__c = true];
   System.debug('##### checkFactureAcompteSize ' + checkIfFactureAcompte.size());
            System.debug('##### checkIfFactureAcompte ' + checkIfFactureAcompte);``` the Id seems incorrect.

Comment: i have this in logs ```##### checkIfFactureAcompte (sofactoapp__Factures_Client__c:{Id=a2u7a000000ItYxAAK, sofactoapp__Amount_exVAT__c=2500.00, sofactoapp__Amount_VAT__c=2637.50, sofactoapp__Offre__c=a347a000000FTgxAAG})``` and ```##### OFFREID a347a000000FTgxAAG```

Comment: and this is coming from debugs in helper class ```|##### offreIdRelateda2u7a000000ItYxAAK``` ```##### offreFromHelperId a347a000000FTgxAAG```

Comment: Let me clarify: In the class that you are testing, have you verified that `offreId` has **in the context of running a test** a value, and one that matches what is created in your test class? | I am not intending to talk down here, but I want to make sure that you know that when a test is running, the class that you are testing does not have access to your "real" data - it only has access to the test data that you create in or from your test class(es).

Comment: Yeah i've tried what you said, i've added the Wrapper method i'm using and trying to cover to be more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120165/discussion-between-moonpie-and-adrien-merignac).